# is there any relation between setOutputFormat and setAudioEncoder

Tags: android, audio, mediarecorder

while using MediaRecorder, the document said:

Set output file format using MediaRecorder.setOutputFormat().
Set the audio encoder using MediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder().

my question: is there any constraint or relation between these two APIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sheds some light on the topic:

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

It's quite unfortunate that this information isn't linked in the mediarecorder API docs.
If you try to encode with AAC+ the native code just silently crashes.